# Need help understanding a relation between the fundamental forms

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

The book I am reading briefly mentions this relation between the fundamental forms but gives no explanation of how they got it.

Take the following as the Weingarten Map/Shape Operator where $\nu$ is the gauss map and f is a surface element.

$$L =  - D\nu  \circ {(Df)^{ - 1}}$$

Then it defines the fundamental forms as...
$$I(X,Y) = \left\langle {X,Y} \right\rangle $$
$$II(X,Y) = I(LX,Y)$$
$$III(X,Y) = I(LX,LY)$$

It goes through all of this and explains it but then it gives me the following relation with no support...

$$III - tr(L)II + \det (L)I = 0$$

Can someone show me how we would go about verifying it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that this equation is a $2$-dimensional phenomenon: it only holds on surfaces. In this case we can use the identities $\mathrm{tr} L = 2 H$ and $\det L = K$, where $H$ and $K$ are the mean curvature and the Gaussian curvature, respectively.

A straightforward verification can be done by computing the left hand side in a suitable basis and appealing to the tensoriality of all the terms. Clearly, at any point of the surface we can take a principal basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ and compute $III - 2 H\, II + K\, I$ on all combinations $\{e_i,e_j\}$ for $i,j=1,2$ to see that this expression indeed vanishes (here I am following **A.Gray et al.**, Modern Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces with Mathematica. Third Ed., p.403, see e.g.[here](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=owEj9TMYo7IC&pg=PA402&lpg=PA402)).

Pretty similarly, **W.Klingenberg** in "[A course in differential geometry](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=8F7vAAAAMAAJ)", p.48, takes the quantity $IV:=(D \nu + \kappa_1 D f)(D \nu + \kappa_2 D f)$ and observes that $IV(e_1,X)=IV(X,e_2)=0$ for an arbitrary $X$ tangent to the surface. Expanding the definitions, one sees that $IV = III - 2 H\, II + K\, I$.

Another way is to observe that $III - \mathrm{tr}(L)II + \det (L)I$ is in fact the [Cayley-Hamilton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) equation for the Weingarten operator $L$.

---

As an aside, I want to take the chance and continue the propaganda of the **abstract index notation**. I will derive this equation along with a particular case of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, following **M.Eastwood**, "Invariant Theory in Differential Geometry", Proceedings of the Centre for Mathematics and its Applciations, 1994, pp.71-78, see [here](http://maths-proceedings.anu.edu.au/CMAProcVol33/CMAProcVol33-Eastwood.pdf).

Since I have spent a bit of time explaining the abstract index notation on this site, see e.g. my answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1269095/2002) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/455574/2002), I will use the conventions form those answers extensively. In particular, the tangent space $T_p S$ to the surface $S$ at a point $p$ will be denoted by $E^a$. The vector bundles are denoted by the same letters as the fibers, so, e.g., $E_a$ will mean both the cotangent space at some point, and the cotangent bundle.

Let us write the Weingarten operator as $L_a{}^b$, and notice that the third fundamental form can be presented as $III_{a b} = g_{c d} L_a{}^c L_b{}^d$, where $g_{a b}$ is the inner product in the tangent space of the chosen point. Also, we write $\mathrm{tr}L = L_a{}^a$. In fact, we use $g_{a b}$ and its inverse $g^{a b}$ tacitly to raise and lower indices ("musical isomorphisms"). Furthermore, $III_a{}^b = (L^2)_a{}^b$. The identity operator  is presented by (the abstract-index version of) the Kronecker symbol $\mathrm{id}_a{}^b \equiv \delta_a{}^b$.

The Cayley-Hamilton theorem is equivalent to an **obvious** fact that on $n$-dimensional vector space all exterior forms of degree $> n$ vanish identically (the latter fact is collectively called the Cayley-Hamilton identity). Moreover, this holds for exterior forms with values in any vector space!

Consider $L_{[a}{}^d L_{b}{}^e \delta_{c]}{}^f \in E_{[abc]}\otimes E^{d e f}$, a $3$-form on $T_p S$ with values in $\otimes^3 T_pS$. From the Cayley-Hamilton identity, this form is identically zero if $\dim T_p S = 2$. In particular, *all the traces* of this quantity are zeroes!

Hopefully, the above paragraphs justify enough the following calculation.
$$
\begin{align}
0_a{}^d & = 6 \, L_{[a}{}^b L_b{}^c \delta_{c]}{}^d\\
& = L_a{}^b L_b{}^c \delta_c{}^d + L_b{}^b L_c{}^c \delta_a{}^d + L_c{}^b L_a{}^c \delta_b{}^d - L_b{}^b L_a{}^c \delta_c{}^d - L_a{}^b L_c{}^c \delta_b{}^d - L_c{}^b L_b{}^c \delta_a{}^d \\
& = (L^2)_a{}^d + (\mathrm{tr}L)^2 \delta_a{}^d + (L^2)_a{}^d - (\mathrm{tr} L) L_a{}^d - (\mathrm{tr} L) L_a{}^d + (\mathrm{tr}L^2) \delta_a{}^d \\
& = 2 (L^2)_a{}^d - 2(\mathrm{tr}L)L_a{}^d + [(\mathrm{tr}L)^2 - \mathrm{tr}(L^2)]\delta_a{}^d
\end{align}
$$

**Exercise**. Show that $(\mathrm{tr}L)^2 - \mathrm{tr}(L^2) = 2\,\det L$ for any $2\times 2$-matrix $L$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Cleared it up very well.