# Proving the first three fundamental forms for Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I need to write w=ae₁+be₂ in terms of the basis {e₁,e₂} of principal directions at p. Further, I need to compute the three fundamental forms at w, that is Iₚ(w),IIₚ(w), IIIₚ(w) while simplifying expressions using the face that e₁,e₂ are principal directions.

Lastly, I need to show that three fundamental forms satisfy the following

IIIₚ(w)-2H(IIₚ(w))+ KIₚ(w)=0

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is good, but you are going to get a ton of downvotes if you do not show some work. What have you tried? Also, please post using MathJax or a like program! Welcome to Mathstack-

Comment: What is H, and what is K?

Comment: @D.Brito $H$ is the mean curvature, and $K$ is the Gaussian curvature of the surface

Comment: Basically, this is a consequence of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. Please read my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1300331/2002).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).