# Why $(\partial_t \nabla _X \omega)Y =-\omega(\partial_t \nabla_X Y)$ means $\partial_t \nabla \omega = \omega * \nabla (\partial _t g)$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

$\omega \in \Gamma(T^*M)$, $X,Y\in \Gamma(TM) $, $(M, g(t))$ is Riemannian manifold whoes metric depends on $t$. If I have
$$
(\partial_t \nabla _X \omega)Y =-\omega(\partial_t \nabla_X Y)
$$
Why  $\partial_t \nabla \omega = \omega * \nabla (\partial _t g)$  ?

What I do: Assuming $\omega =\omega_i dx^i, X=x^i\partial_i, Y=y^i\partial_i$, I can get
$$
-\omega(\partial_t \nabla_X Y) = -\omega_k x^i y^j \partial_t \Gamma_{ij}^k \tag{1}
$$
I think (1) means that $\partial_t \nabla \omega = \omega * \nabla (\partial _t g) +  \omega * (\partial_t g^{-1}\nabla g)  $ by the definition of $\Gamma_{ij}^k$. Where is the wrong ?

---

Pictures belos are from Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow, where $h=\partial_t g$.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: What is the $*$?

Comment: @C.F.G   It is defined in first picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to start with the formula from **Proposition 2.3.1** (p.28 in Topping's lectures):
$$
\langle \tfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \nabla_{X}Y, Z \rangle = \tfrac{1}{2}[(\nabla_{Y}h)(X,Z) + (\nabla_{X}h)(Y,Z) - (\nabla_{Z}h)(X,Y)]
$$
I will rewrite this formula using the [abstract index notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/455478/2002), as in my opinion it clarifies the underlying meaning of the things much better, that the classical notation. So, here it is.
$$
g_{b c} X^a Z^c \dot{\nabla}_a Y^b = \tfrac{1}{2}(X^b Y^a Z^c \nabla_a h_{b c} + X^a Y^b Z^c \nabla_a h_{b c} - X^b Y^c Z^a \nabla_a h_{b c}) \tag{1}
$$

Here we are talking about a family of metrics $g = g(t)$ on a smooth manifold, $t$ is a real parameter from some interval, $\nabla = \nabla(t)$ is the family of Levi-Civita connections, corresponding to $g = g(t)$. At a fixed moment of $t$ we consider the derivatives $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}g =: h$ which we could also denote as $\dot{g}$, so that $\dot{\nabla}:= \tfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \nabla$ is a shorter notation for the $t$-derivative of the Levi-Civita connection$\nabla = \nabla(t)$.

The Riemannian metrics $g_{a b}$ are all non-degenerate, and therefore invertible, that is there are sections, denoted as $g^{a b}$, such that:
$$
g^{a b} g_{b c} = \delta^a{}_c \tag{2}
$$
where $\delta^a{}_b$ is a tensorial appearance of the identity operator, also known as Kronecker's symbol. Notice, that unlike $g$-s, the $\delta$ is constant, and, in particular, does not depend on $t$.

By the virtue of (2), the upper or lower position of the index is inessential in Riemannian geometry (cf. the [musical isomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism)), so that we can use $g^{a b}$ to get rid of the metric in the left hand side of (1). Furthermore, since the fields $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are arbitrary, one can show (this is an exercise which can be performed by pure thought!), that (1) is equivalent to
$$
\dot{\nabla}_a Y^b = (Y * \nabla h)_a{}^b \tag{3}
$$
which is the **Remark 2.3.3** in Topping's lectures (p.29 in my copy). See my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4259949/2002) regarding the meaning of $*$-notation.

More accurately, let us first **rename** the dummy indices in (1), so that all the right-hand side (RHS) fields $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ have the same indices as their peers in the left-hand side (LHS) of the equation:
$$
g_{b c} X^a Z^c \dot{\nabla}_a Y^b = \tfrac{1}{2}(X^a Y^b Z^c \nabla_b h_{a c} + X^a Y^b Z^c \nabla_a h_{b c} - X^a Y^b Z^c \nabla_c h_{a b})
$$

We can now factor out $X$ and $Z$ on both sides:

$$
X^a Z^c (g_{b c} \dot{\nabla}_a Y^b) = X^a Z^c  \big( \tfrac{1}{2}(Y^b \nabla_b h_{a c} + Y^b \nabla_a h_{b c} - Y^b \nabla_c h_{a b}) \big)
$$

The fields $X$ and $Z$ are arbitrary, which implies that

$$
g_{b c} \dot{\nabla}_a Y^b = \tfrac{1}{2}(Y^b \nabla_b h_{a c} + Y^b \nabla_a h_{b c} - Y^b \nabla_c h_{a b})
$$

We can now use (2) to eliminate the metric on the LHS:

$$
g^{d c} g_{b c} \dot{\nabla}_a Y^b = \tfrac{1}{2} g^{d c}  (Y^b \nabla_b h_{a c} + Y^b \nabla_a h_{b c} - Y^b \nabla_c h_{a b})
$$

which becomes

$$
\delta^{d}{}_{b} \dot{\nabla}_a Y^b = \tfrac{1}{2} g^{d c}  (Y^b \nabla_b h_{a c} + Y^b \nabla_a h_{b c} - Y^b \nabla_c h_{a b})
$$

or

$$
\dot{\nabla}_a Y^d = \tfrac{1}{2} g^{d c}  (Y^b \nabla_b h_{a c} + Y^b \nabla_a h_{b c} - Y^b \nabla_c h_{a b})
$$

and, renaming the indices one more time,

$$
\dot{\nabla}_a Y^b = \tfrac{1}{2} g^{b c}  (Y^d \nabla_d h_{a c} + Y^d \nabla_a h_{d c} - Y^b \nabla_c h_{a d})
$$

we obtain an explicit expression for (3).

The equation (2.3.2) in the lectures gives a clear calculation (abstract indices are less helpful in this case) for the identity
$$
(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \nabla_{X}\omega)(Y) = - \omega(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \nabla_{X} Y)
$$

which we can rewrite with abstract indices and our above conventions as
$$
X^a Y^b \dot{\nabla}_{a} \omega_b = - X^a \omega_b \dot{\nabla}_{a} Y^b
$$

Observing, that $X$ is arbitrary, and substituting (3) to eliminate $\dot{\nabla}_{a} Y^b$ from the RHS, in a similar fashion as above, we extract the sought formula:
$$
\dot{\nabla}_a \omega_b = (\omega * \nabla h)_{a b} \tag{4}
$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why (1) is equivalent to (3).  Besides, the Remark 2.3.3 in Topping's lecture is $\dot\nabla Y = Y * \nabla h$.

Comment: @lanse7pty you are right. I was in a hurry and made a few typos and mistakes. Unfortunately, I don't have much time to do these exercises nowadays. I fixed the typos and expanded the calculations. Please see if it is more clear for you now.

Comment: Thanks,  I understand you now.