# Commutativity of $\nabla$ and $\Delta$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a (closed if necessary) Riemannian manifold with Levi-Civita connection

Let $\nabla^*$ be the formal adjoint of $\nabla$ with respect to the $L^2$ inner product. Let $\Delta=\nabla^*\nabla$ denote the Laplacian.

**Question 1:** In general, do we have $\nabla\circ\Delta$=$\Delta\circ\nabla$, as operators $C^\infty(M)\to C^\infty(M)\otimes C^\infty(T^*M)$?

**Question 2:** If not, is this relation true if the metric is flat?

*Comment:* I feel that the answer to Q2 at least must be yes, but I am not good with these computations. So I would appreciate it if someone could work through the computation (or perhaps share a reference) for the commutator $[\nabla,\Delta]$ involving the curvature terms.

Comment: In general, there will be some differences due to the curvature terms. For a special case, you can look up Bochner's formula.

Comment: If the metric is flat, the problem reduces to compute $(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j ^2} )\circ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j_0}}$ and Schwarz lemma gives the answer.

Comment: You may find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4259949/2002) my answer useful for getting a more general perspective on this identity.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin Thanks, indeed that looks useful (somehow it did not appear in my search the first time). Does your answer imply that there exist constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that $\|\nabla\Delta A-\Delta\nabla A\|\leq C_1\|\nabla R\|\|A\|+C_2\|R\|\|\nabla A\|$, where norms are induced from the Riemannian metric?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea about the estimates. It looks like a totally new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has been mentioned in comment, by Bochner's formula for function $f$ the answer is clear:

$$\Delta\nabla_if =
\nabla_i\Delta f + \mbox{R}_{ij}\nabla_jf.$$

Obviously in flat metrics we have $\mbox{R}_{ij}=0$ and ..

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to derive your formula from Bochner's formula, as stated here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_formula?

Comment: See for details [Chow, Bennett; Lu, Peng; Ni, Lei (2006), Hamilton's Ricci flow](https://books.google.com/books?id=dQYPCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false) page 18.

Comment: Thanks, now it's been reduced to an easier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4403813/two-equalities-involving-covariant-derivatives) that I still can't quite answer.