# Estimating norm of the commutator $[\nabla,\Delta]$ on tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$. Let $\Delta$ be the Laplacian on tensor fields, which locally satisfies
$$
\Delta A = g^{ij}(\nabla _{\partial_i}\nabla _{\partial_j}A - \nabla_{\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j}A)
$$
for any tensor field $A$.

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255586/how-to-show-nabla-delta-a-delta-nabla-a-nabla-rm-arm-nabla-a), we know that
$$\nabla(\Delta A)-\Delta(\nabla A)=\nabla Rm *A+Rm*\nabla A,$$
where for tensors $T_1$ and $T_2$, the notation $T_1*T_2$ means some linear combination of contractions of $T_1$ and $T_2$.

**Question:** Do there exist constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that
$$\|\nabla(\Delta A)-\Delta(\nabla)A\|\leq C_1\|\nabla Rm\|\|A\|+C_2\|Rm\|\|\nabla A\|,$$
where the various norms are induced from the Riemannian metric $g$? Here $C_1$ and $C_2$ should only depend on the type $(p,q)$ of the tensor $A$.

*Clarification:* Here $\|\cdot\|$ denotes either the pointwise or the $L^2$-norm. We can assume $M$ to be compact if that helps.

Comment: Is $\|\cdot\|$ the pointwise norm?

Comment: @Deane I'm interested both when $\|\cdot\|$ is the pointwise norm or the $L^2$-norm. I should say I'm really only interested in the case when $(M,g)$ has bounded geometry (or even compact $M$), but I'm not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Pointwise: 1) Write everything out in components with respect to an orthonormal frame. 2) Observe that, given $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, $|ab| = |a||b|$. 3) Observe that, with respect to an orthonormal frame, the components of a tensor $T$ satisfy (say, for a 4-order tensor) $|T_{ijkl}|\le \|T\|$.

Comment: For $L^2$, this does not work, because $\|fg\|_2$ cannot be bounded by $\|f\|_2\|g\|_2$.